# Redirect to other html pages based on time

Tags: javascript, html

Not sure if it is possible to write a HTML page and make this page redirect to page1 Monday to Friday : 9am to 5pm. And the other times redirect to page2?

Comment: The proper way to do this is to have this handled on the server using server time, not on the HTML side. Based on the server time you should serve the appropriate pages. Also, yes it's possible - What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this cannot be done using only html, but it can be done using Javascript

Here is a simple code for it

```
<script>

function myFunction() {

    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay();

    if(d>0 && d<6){

       //This function is used to redirect in javascript
       window.location.replace("page1.html");

    } else{

       window.location.replace("page2.html");

    }



}

</script>
```

The getDay() method returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6) for the specified date.

Note: Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so on.

**Edit:** This will redirect you to page 1 from Monday to Friday, at the limits of 00:00, if you are looking for a specific time then there is another function for it, and it depends on the user timezone.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it many languages. For example, you can use JavaScript like what Yassir has done... or you can use PHP. Something like this:

```
<?php
$d = date("D"); //day
$h = date("H", mktime(date("H"))); //hour
if($d == 'Mon' || $d == 'Tue' || $d == 'Wed' || $d == 'Thu' || $d == 'Fri' && ($h >= 9 && $h < 17)) {
  header('Location: http://www.domain.com/page1');
} else {
  header('Location: http://www.domain.com/page2');
}  
?>
```

You can change the time zones by changing this:

```
$h = date("H", mktime(date("H")));
```

to

```
$h = date("H", mktime(date("H")-2));
```

or

```
$h = date("H", mktime(date("H")+2));
```