# Show different HTML page based on time

Tags: html

I'm trying to load certain HTML pages during certain times, i managed to do it with images with the following script:

```
<head>
    <title>Il Forno menu</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var menukaarts = [  // add path to directory if necessary
 "/nl/image1.jpg",
 "/nl/image2.jpg"  // NOTE: no comma after last entry
 ];
 function TODimage() {
 var now = new Date();
 hr = now.getHours();                               // alert(hr);  // for testing
 var DJ = 0;                                               // midnight to  5:59 am
 if ((hr >= 15) && (hr < 24)) { DJ = 1; } // Dinner
 document.getElementById('image').src = images[DJ];
 document.getElementById('image').alt = images[DJ];
 }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="TODimage()">
    <img id="image" src="" alt="image">
    
</body>
```

But i would like to load HTML pages now....

HTML1.html is just one page
HTML2.html would be 3 pages (images that you have to be able to change between with a click)

I tryed modifying the script but failed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect to other html pages based on time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816314/redirect-to-other-html-pages-based-on-time)

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve the html data using the `fetch` function and parse it using the `DOMParser` class which returns an object similar to `document`. so you can use every dom method and function on it.

```js
var pagesUrl = ["/", "/2", "/3"]

function loadPage(url) {
    return fetch(url)
        .then(resp => response.text())
        .then(html => {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');})
            
            return doc
        })
        .catch(err => console.warn(err))
}

function placeData(doc){
    // here is up to you, depending on where exactly the data of the retrieved HTML you want to be placed

    document.title = doc.title
    document.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML
}

// the below code is just an example. you can implement your own way of selecting a URL

var n = 0;

setInterval(() => {
    var url = pagesUrl[n1]
    
    loadPage(url).then(doc => placeData(doc))

    n++
}, 5_000)
```